# Is it possible to append text to a text element in SVG?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to append a new text element at the end of the data label on clicking on that particular text. Is it possible? I tried to add this to my code and it is not displaying the text to be added:

```
circleGroup.selectAll("text")
           .data(data)
           .enter()
           .append("text")
           .text(function (d) {
                if (d.label) {
                    return d.label;
                }
                   return "";
                })
           .attr("x", function (d) {
                  return x(d.time) + 6;
            })
           .attr("y", function (d) {
                    return y(d.plotY) + 4;
                })
           .attr("font-size", "10px")
           .attr("fill", "#2d3d45")
           .on("click", function(d) {
                    d3.select(this).append("text").text("[A]").attr("x", function(d) {return x(d.time) + 25;}).attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.plotY) + 4;});

           });
```

But it has been appended to the data label.

[image]

Why is the "[A]" text not getting displayed even after being appended to the parent text element ?

Comment: You have to append a `<tspan>`, not a `<text>`.

Comment: you are correct! appending <tspan> works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Funnily enough, I tried to close this as a dupe but I couldn't find any question regarding this specific issue (there are tons of questions about appending a `<text>` to a `<rect>` or to a `<circle>`, but no one about appending a `<text>` to another `<text>`). So, I just wrote a proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you **cannot** append a `<text>` element to another `<text>` element.

According to the [SVG specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermTextContentChildElement),

> A text content child element is a text content element that is allowed as a descendant of another text content element. In SVG 1.1, the text content child elements are the following: ‘altGlyph’, ‘textPath’, ‘tref’ and ‘tspan’.

Therefore, the solution is appending a `<tspan>` instead:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .attr("y", 20)
  .text("I am the text element")
  .append("tspan")
  .attr("dy", "1.5em")
  .attr("x", 20)
  .text("And I am the tspan element")
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

That will give you this structure:

```
<text x="20" y="20">I am the text element
    <tspan dy="1.5em" x="20">And I am the tspan element</tspan>
</text>
```